# df column replace with space in anything that falls in a symbol

Tags: python, string, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a df column which has a lot of tags. I want to clean them out.

```
df['text_col'].tolist()


['n</li></ul>',
 '<p> bla bla bla </p>',
 'bla bla </b>, </li>, <li>, </ul>',
 'bla bla <strong>bla </strong>: <h3> </h3>, <ul>,<b> </p>']
```

I see two ways of cleaning it.

1. Create a list of all tags I find in the text and then replace those with the empty string '' (can be laborious task to maintain the list)
2. Some logic to remove anything that comes in < and > tags.

I dont know of any other way other than str replace.. but it doesnt quite do what I explained above.

```
df["text_col"].str.replace("</p>"," ")
```

How do I remove all the tags and clean the text_col?

Comment: [n</li></ul>" your example starts with an unclosed double quotation mark. Have you made some mistake in writing out the sample output? (Also the letter 'n')

Comment: @SavvY - have changed it. Do you know how to solve the problem? :)

Comment: I got somthing to help you, finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of looking around this is what I found:

```
import re

x=['n</li></ul>',
 '<p> bla bla bla </p>',
 'bla bla </b>, </li>, <li>, </ul>',
 'bla bla <strong>bla </strong>: <h3> </h3>, <ul>,<b> </p>']

for item in x:
    item = re.sub("<.*?>|,|:", "", item)
    item=' '.join(item.split())
    print(item)
```

Outputs:

```
n
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
```

I edited my answer again to refine it a little more. This should definitely answer your question. Thank regex :) .